# could not reorder column in gtsummary

Tags: gtsummary

`your text`iris %>%
`your text`select(Sepal.Length,Species) %>%
`your text`tbl_summary(by = Species) %>%
`your text`add_p()

By default the species are ordered as setosa, versicolor and virginica. How do I change this order  if I want versicolor, setosa and viriginca?

Comment: make the variable a factor in the data frame before you pass it to `tbl_summary()`. Set the order of the factor levels in the order you want them to appear in the table.